# Soften/Feather Edge of 3D Sphere (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, transparency, volumetrics, shader-nodes

How can I soften the edge of a 3D Sphere? Using Volume?
I've tried searching for the answer but I can't find a way to completely soften the edge. I'm using Cycles.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

(Visual reference made in Photoshop)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using *Volume* was the correct intention. A *Surface* shader will always have a hard edge. But on the other hand a volume will hardly ever be opaque but look like it has subsurface scattering, no matter how high you set the density (at least not if you want to keep a soft edge), but maybe there are some settings that get close to it.

So there are two possibilities: if you want it to look like your example image with no shading on it, you can simply plug an *Emission* shader into the *Volume* of the *Material Output* node.

This alone might produce a slightly soft edge, to increase the effect like in your image, you might want to use a *Quadratic Sphere* gradient maybe together with a *Color Ramp* etc. to tweak the look. To make the falloff even smoother you can plug the gradient output into a *Math* node set to *Power*, with an *Exponent* > 1:

[image: volume emission]

If you want to have a soft surface that also reacts to light and shows shadows, you can plug the gradient and color ramp setup into a *Principled Volume* shader. To intensify the density you should multiply the ramp's output with some factor:

[image: density volume]

These are just basic setups to give you an idea, I guess there are lots of ways to fine tune this.

Answer (score 4):

[@Gordon's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/278776/35559) is probably more physically correct (depending on what you *mean* by softening the boundary of a sphere, in 3D.)

If you don't need a spherical response to external lighting, though,  a variation on this might be acceptable:

[image]

... avoiding the expense of volumetrics.

[image]

Comment: Ha, of course that's a way to go as well... (by the way, for beginners it's always better to see the full node although the name already says _Principled BSDF_).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Quite right. Wilko. :)

Comment: ...oh, I forgot to mention, pure emission in volume isn't so expensive ;)

Comment: @Gordon ahh. OK.. ..? Doesn't the ray have to step through the volume, evaluating at every step? Whereas a Surface shader-ray gets to jump straight to the next triangle  en route, in the BVH?

Comment: Thank you everyone who made comments on the post. I really appreciate it!! I will look into all of these. @GordonBrinkmann @ robinbetts @ moonboots

Comment: @RobinBetts Sorry, I'm not so much into technical details. What I meant was, while rendering volumes with density (like smoke etc.) can take really long, a pure emission (like fire without smoke) renders quite quick. So I don't know about what exactly happens there, but I see it in render times.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: OK same answer as Robin, just another setup...

It's not clear what you want, if your sphere is supposed to be transparent on its periphery you could use a *Layer Weight* as factor between an *Emission* (or *Diffuse*) and a *Transparent* node:

[image]